# Drawing bus routes on OpenStreetMap with mapnik

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik

I have successfully set up PostgreSQL with PostGIS and MapNik to serve map tiles. The database is populated with data from OpenStreetMap project. I can see that bus routes are in the data-set, but I have hard time displaying them on the tiles.

Can anybody provide some advice how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Well the answer isn't that easy and includes different aspects:

1. **Tagging schema:**
   Using so called "relation" container objects, OSM groups ways and node objects together. For PT this means, that they contain e.g. a sequence of road segments/ways and the bus stops itself:
   http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Public_Transport
   http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Buses
   Be aware, that there are various ways to tag PT, they all depend on how much details you want to express.
2. **rendering routes:**
   This is basically selecting the relations and apply a coloring corresponding to tags and/or classification. Mapnik might be used with own rulesets, or use preprocessed geofiles by custom scripts. You might have a look here, how **this guys** do the work:

   - http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/öpnvkarte
   - http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openptmap

Answer (score 1):

I did this and [described some details on this old blog post](http://harrywood.co.uk/blog/2011/03/28/bus-route-rendering-at-rewiredstate/). My basic approach was to copying the XML stylesheet config for ferries. At the time that was found in the `‘inc/layer-ferry-routes.xml.inc’` file. However that was a long time ago on old version of mapnik. Nowadays we don't even tend to use the XML stylesheets, although looking at how ferry routes are rendered in a newer stylesheet, might still be a good trick.